# How can I intercept/replace the New button click on the sub-grid?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

Let's start by establishing that some of the D365 out-of-the-box functionality can be a little clunky at times.

For 1:N relationships, when you press the "+ New" button on the sub-grid the behavior changes depending on whether the relationship is configured as either "Optional" or "Business Required". It either lets you search and add an existing record (optional) or it always makes you create a new record (business required).

This is fine. I can control that.

For N:N relationships that "+ New" button on the sub-grid only ever lets me search for an existing record. In this instance I only ever want to create a new record each time.

The scenario is relating the `systemuser` entity to a custom entity (via N:N relationship) to indicate their "specialization" in a field, it's called. I have another lookup entity that indicates the field and my custom specialization entity has the following fields:

1. Name (text)
2. Field (lookup to the specialization field)
3. Level (to gauge their degree of specialization)

If I was to reuse an existing record it would also be associated with another user's specialization. If I was to change the level of ability they have in that field it would impact any other users connected with that record.

I need to create a new record each time. If I can replace that click functionality I can just pop up a new dialog and then create the records myself.

Failing this, I need to replace the entire sub-grid control as a custom web resource, please don't make me do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar implementation called Banker Skillset in my project. You can search & add the existing record but error will be thrown saying “already record is associated with another record”. I don’t understand that then why “Add existing” button is allowed using inline search lookup in this N:N scenario. Like you said who’ll remap (take out & give it to) someone else record like this.

1. You can still make systemuser & specialization lookups as mandatory in that Manual N:N entity - user specialization. If you enable Quick create of that N:N intersect entity, QC form will drop on top when you click (+) in subgrid
2. Another option is using `Xrm.Utility.lookupObjects` to allow users to choose multiple specialization and then add the N:N with default level (degree of specialization) for all the selected records. Then user can choose the individual level using editable grid. For this you have to hide the existing (+) buttons & start creating a new ribbon button using Ribbon workbench

[Read more](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2018/06/show-lookup-dialog-in-dynamics-365-v9-0/)

Comment: Hey Arun, thanks for that but I'm not using a manual specialization entity that intersects the specialisation and the systemuser.  My specialisation just lists the field and degree.  I'm using a standard N:N relationship to link that specialisation entity with the systemuser so I don't have access to specify whether either side is optional or mandatory.  I did this because I use the same specialization entity elsewhere to record other things that also require specializations, not just systemusers.

Comment: I was already thinking of using the Xrm.Utility.lookupObjects and other means of creating a dialog to allow selection.  That's not the problem.
The problem is that would require me to have a button on the ribbon at the top of the form when my subgrid is in the middle of the form.  There's a disconnect there and I wanted to replace the button right there on the subgrid and that'd give my users a more meaningful experience.

Comment: @Fooksie then how did you get Name & Level in that N:N ?

Comment: Arun, speciality IS a custom entity that links field with degree of speciality.  It doesn't have a systemuser field on it though.  There's no direct intersect with the systemuser on it.  That's provided by an out-of-the-box N:N relationship.  I use the specialization entity that is a combination of field and degree on a few separate places and I didn't want to create multiple custom entities to record the exact same data just because where it intersects is different

Comment: Hi Fooksie, if your scenario allows it, I think Arun intersect entity is a better approach, the N:N relationship is useful in some cases, but most likely it will give you trouble, it will save you some disk space not using the intersect entity.

Comment: Although I don't want to do it this way, it looks like I'm going to have to create a Specialization entity that has a direct relationship for every scenario I need to use it.  At the moment it's only 2-3, but that really stinks.